# How to highlight Jquery datepicker dates fetched from MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a MySQL table where a user's available dates are inserted. Now what I want to do is to fetch those "dates" and highlight them on a JQuery datepicker calendar.

Here's my code.

```
// HTML
<div id="datetimepicker1"></div>


// Adapter-fetch.php

$global_user_id = 5;

$find_query = $db->prepare("SELECT date_available FROM user_dates WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$find_query->bindParam(':user_id', $global_user_id);
$find_query->execute();
$result_find = $find_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($result_find) > 0) {
 foreach($result_find as $row) {
  $date_available = $row['date_available'];

  echo $date_available;
 }
} else {
  echo 'No dates available';
}



// JAVASCRIPT
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.post('<?php echo $project_name; ?>/snippets/adapter-fetch.php', {},
    function(data) {

     alert(data);
  
     var SelectedDates = {};
     SelectedDates[new Date('2021/6/6')] = new Date('2021/6/6').toString();

     $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
     multidate: true,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
      if (Highlight) {
        return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
      } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
     }
    });
   });
 });
</script>

// MYSQL user_dates Table
2021-06-02
2021-06-03
2021-06-01
```

So the above code works as is. Now what I want to do is replace the current "SelectedDates" to the ones I am fetching using "adapter-fetch.php". When I alert the "data", it returns the dates results like this "2021-06-022021-06-032021-06-01". So I am wondering how can I modify this data to replace the current dates in the "SelectedDates" and make it work?

Comment: try `console.log(data)` what does that show?

Comment: It shows the same data format "2021-06-022021-06-032021-06-01".

Comment: really, no comma separation? No delimiters at all?

Comment: its a little surprising for a response. You'd expect a json encoded structure of some kind

Comment: Correct. no comma separation or delimiters. It shows exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: Wouldn't it only show the json encoded structure if I echo out the php like this "echo json_encode($date_available);"?

Comment: I just posted an answer. I think you need to set the dataType expectation from the server. Can you test my code in your setting and tell me what the console.log() statement shows? You'll probably get some error, but I'd like to know what the log() shows

Comment: Argh - I just saw the first half of your questin, which due to my small monitor, I missed the first time. Give me a minute to reformat my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your $.post into a $ajax, because I wanted to set the `dataType` attribute to JSON since that's what we're going to use in the callback. Edit your php to return JSON

```
<?php
    // Adapter-fetch.php
    $global_user_id = 5;
    $find_query = $db->prepare("SELECT date_available FROM user_dates WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $find_query->bindParam(':user_id', $global_user_id);
    $find_query->execute();
    $result_find = $find_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $dates = []; // init the array
    if(count($result_find) > 0) {
     foreach($result_find as $row) $dates[]=$row['date_available'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dates);

?>
```

update your code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo $project_name; ?>/snippets/adapter-fetch.php',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(highlighted) {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        multidate: true,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
          for(let x=0;x<highlighted.length;x++) {
            //console.log(highlighted[x],date)
            let h = highlighted[x], td = date.toISOString().split("T")[0]
            if (h === td) {
              return [true, 'Highlighted', '']; // that 3rd index is the tooltip text
            }
          }
          return [true, '']; // default if not a highlight
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow that's a great solution. Just one thing. The datepicker calendar isn't showing up now. Can you tell why that might be?

Comment: when you check the network tab, do you see the response coming in with the dates? Are they a different format?

Comment: Sorry am not too familiar with the "Network" tab. But I see the console log for "console.log(getDatesFromResponse('2021-06-022021-06-032021-06-01'));". However I don't see the log for the "console.log(highlighted)".

Comment: In the Network tab and under adapter-fetch.php, the response shows the dates as such "2021-06-022021-06-032021-06-01". Which is correct since they haven't yet been modified by your javascript code, yes?

Comment: ok. updated answer. Let me know how it works out

Comment: Alright so now the Calendar shows up.  I even get the console log format in the correct format like this "["2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-01"]". However these dates are not being highlighted on the Calendar itself.

Comment: ok, now we're cooking! I just realized my `beforeShowDay: function(date` needed adjustment, so check out that part of the revised answer.

Comment: Strange. It's still not highlighting.

Comment: I updated the beforeShowDay fucntion with a `console.log` statement. That will create alot of output to your console, but I need you to just copy a couple of them and put here.

Comment: Sure. They go like this. "2021-06-02 Sun May 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" "2021-06-03 Sun May 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" "2021-06-01 Sun May 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

Comment: ok, updated answer. let me know if it helps

Comment: also, I'm assuming you have a class `.Highlighted` that has css to show these? like `.Highlighted { background:#f00; color:#fff;}`

Comment: Yes I have a css class called .Highlighted. It does show the highlight dates in my original code. But even with your updated answer, it's still not showing the highlights.

Comment: So have you figured out a solution? I've been trying and nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's funny. I just figured it out myself. I haven't tried your code yet. But I finally understood the issue. The problem was that the beforeShowDay "date" was returning different format of the date when compared to the one I was fetching from the database. So all I had to do was reformat the date to match that. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my original question. This ajax code will fetch the dates from mysql database and highlight them on a calendar.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  let month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(d.getDate());
  const year = String(d.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<?php echo $project_name; ?>/snippets/adapter-fetch.php',
  data: {},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(highlighted) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      multidate: true,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        newDate = formattedDate(date);
        for(let x=0; x < highlighted.length; x++) {
        console.log(highlighted[x].toString(), newDate.toString());

        if (highlighted[x] === newDate) {
          return [true, 'Highlighted', ''];
        }
      }
      return [true, '']; // default if not a highlight
     }
    });
   }
  });
});
</script>
```